# Swift iOS User input link and search for RSS feed

Tags: ios, swift, rss

I would like to add a feature to my RSS Reader that i am making that lets a user put in a link (eg. user inputs apple.com) and it shows them a list of feeds for that website like "apple hot news, apple developer" and so on. if anyone could tell me how i could start about doing that, that would be great, thanks!